# Display data from sqlite-database and XML file in a TextView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sqlite

I want to insert new rows in my table from a XML resource.

I want to print dynamically buttons in first activity, the number of buttons depends from how many rows are in table.

**For example:**

```
TABLE_NAME = "languages"

row1: LANGUAGE_NAME = "english", LANGUAGE_DESCRIPTION = "Some words in english"
row2: LANGUAGE_NAME = "italian", LANGUAGE_DESCRIPTION = "Some words in italian"
```

I want to display two buttons.

When I click on button which display "english" I want to see in a TextView in second_activity just "Some words in english".

I've tried a lot in this last month but I always failed.

Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must get Data from your XML file by parsing it and then persist data into your sqlite database and then just get data from your database and use it in your application

this is a [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) to parse data from XML
and this is a [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) to use a sqlite database on android
Hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

Simple:
Query your database, get the number of fields from your request, fetch your data and then you could work with a listView to inflate your buttons.

Comment: I'm too much noob for understand your idea. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
    DatabaseHandler dh;
                    SQLiteDatabase db;
                ArrayList<String>= lang_descrip;
                    db = dh.getReadableDatabase();
                                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                                        "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME +"WHERE "+LANGUAGE_NAME+"=english", null);
                    if (cursor != null)
                for(int i=0;i<=cursor.getCount();i++){
                                cursor.moveToFirst();
                    lang_descrip.add(cursor.getString(1));

//if you have 2nd column as description
            }
        //now u can use lang_descrip to get the size of it and create the number of buttons based on size


 int size=lang_descrip.size();
    //now you can use for loop for creating number of buttons with setting its text from lang_descrip's values


 for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText(lang_descrip.get(i).toString());

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    LayoutParams layParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.addView(myButton, layParam);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to display language name in a button and language description in a TextView in a new activity.